# Making custom button background transparent in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I am making a custom button in wxWidgets and i would like it to be a rounded rectangle shape. The problem i am facing is that the edges of the button still show the background colour

[image].

The code for the custom button is going to be attached. I appreciate it.

```
#include "CustomButton.h"
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/dcbuffer.h>
#include <wx/graphics.h>

CustomButton::CustomButton(wxWindow* parent, const wxString& label, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size) :
    wxWindow(parent, wxID_ANY, pos, size)
{
    this->SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_PAINT);

    this->Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &CustomButton::OnPaint, this);
}

void CustomButton::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& evt)
{
    wxAutoBufferedPaintDC dc(this);
    dc.Clear();

    wxGraphicsContext* gc = wxGraphicsContext::Create(dc);

    if (gc) {
        wxPoint btnOrigin = wxPoint(0, 0);
        wxSize btnSize = this->GetSize();

        int radius = wxMin(GetSize().GetWidth(), GetSize().GetHeight()) / 4;
        gc->SetPen(wxPen(wxColour(0, 0, 0), 1));
        gc->SetBrush(wxBrush(wxColor(200, 55, 100, 128)));
        gc->DrawRoundedRectangle(btnOrigin.x, btnOrigin.y, btnSize.GetWidth(), btnSize.GetHeight(), radius);
        gc->SetFont(*wxNORMAL_FONT, wxColor(28, 34, 56));
        wxString text = "Button";

        double textWidth, textHeight;
        gc->GetTextExtent(text, &textWidth, &textHeight);
        gc->DrawText(text, btnOrigin.x + btnSize.GetWidth() / 2.0 - textWidth / 2.0, btnOrigin.y + btnSize.GetHeight() / 2.0 - textHeight / 2.0);
        delete gc;
    }
    
    this->Update();
    this->Refresh();
    evt.Skip();
}
```

I tried using a transparent brush to paint the background first before painting the rectangle. Didint work. I tried making the device context using wxPaintDC. Didnt work. I tried setting the background style to wxBG_STYLE_TRANSPARENT. I was getting runtime error. I am still a beginner at wxWidgets so i would really appreciate the help

Comment: what platform? What wx version? What is exact run-time error? Why do you use wxWindow and not wxPanel or wxControl?

Comment: I am usiing windows. The person i was watching on youtube made custom controls using wxWindow so i thought that was the best practice

Comment: I also asked what was the exact run-time error you mentioned. I also presume you running the `Debug` build of everything and can get a backtrace on the error...

Comment: The error was wxBG_STYLE_TRANSPARENT styl;e cane only be set before Create()-ing the window. I already handled that error.
I tried exporting the button as a bitmap png and the borders appeared to be transparent, but the borders are not transparent in the apploication window.

Comment: what's the difference between you simple test case and the app you are working on? Put some more code in here to make it not working